# Difference between output of probabilistic and ordinary least squares regressions

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

If I execute the commands

```
my_reg = LinearRegression()
lin.reg.fit(X,Y)
```

I train my model. To my understanding training a model is calculating coefficient estimators.

I do not really understand the difference between this and e.g.

```
scipy.stats.linregress(X,Y)
```

calculating a 'normal' regression that also gives me the coefficient estimators and all the other statistics connected with it.

Could anyone tell me what is the difference here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both solve the exact same objective, which is minimizing the mean squared error. However the second method can answer "how confident it is that slope is not zero, i.e. $Y$ is correlated with $X$?" via p-value.

**In detail**

Lets denote the data as $(X, Y) = \{(x_n, y_n)|x_n \in \mathbb{R}^D, y_n \in \mathbb{R}\}$. And the regression as $\hat{y} = Ax+B$.

Extra quantities returned by `scipy.stats.linregress(X,Y)` are: rvalue ($r$), and pvalue ($p$).

In statistics, $r^2$ (known as [r-squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination)) measures the "goodness-of-fit" . That is, as regression $\hat{y}=Ax+B$ gets closer to observation $y$, $r^2$ gets closer to $1$. Since it is a function of $y$ and $\hat{y}$, it can be calculated for the first method too. So no difference here.

However, $p$ is specific to second method. `scipy.stats.linregress(X,Y)` adds a **normality assumption** to noise, i.e. assumes $\epsilon \sim  N(0, \sigma^2)$ where $$\epsilon = y - \overbrace{Ax+B}^{\hat{y}}$$
On the basis of this assumption, it can answer an **additional question**: "how confident it is that the slope is not zero?". The first method cannot answer this question.

For example, suppose the estimated slope is $2.1$ for both methods, we still cannot tell whether this slope is significant or $Y$ is actually independent of $X$. Unless we look at the value of $p$. For example, for $p < 0.01$ we are confident (at significance level $0.01$) that $Y$ is correlated with $X$, but for $p > 0.1$ we cannot be confident, i.e. slope $2.1$ could be due to chance and $Y$ might be independent of $X$.

[This link](https://stattrek.com/regression/slope-test.aspx) gives more details on how p-value is actually calculated in second method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in the conceptual sense - both methods calculate linear regression coefficients. The difference lies in the interface - while through `scipy.stats` you gain the coefficients directly (and it is up to you to put them into an equation to calculate the predictions), `scikit-learn` wraps them into a model object so that you can use it in a similar fashion to other ML models such as decision trees, for example. (Actually, you can obtain the regression coefficients from the fitted `scikit-learn` model using `my_reg.coef_`.)

Answer (score 0):

as I know, OLS algo is sensible to Outliers & Multicollinearity

Limitations of MLE: it systematically underestimate VaR, as is ML estimator of VaR is biased - this is an instance of *overfitting*

LS need data of *Normal* Distribution, for MLE are used *Non-parametric* (real) data

Compared to K-means in Unsupervesed Algos, MLE can work with overlapping classses, K-means only with lineary separable data

Main difference: MLE is considered to be more general algo than LS, and is used in Generalized Linear Models (like ANOVA, ANCOVA - multivariable regression with categorical features, [covariates and confounders](https://www.foldercase.com/blog-covariates-and-confounders-an-introduction.php) - e.g. in [Control of confounding](https://www.dovepress.com/control-of-confounding-in-the-analysis-phase-ndash-an-overview-for-cli-peer-reviewed-fulltext-article-CLEP)) for a variety of other distributions from the exponential family for the residuals - *no assumption for residuals to follow a conditionally normal distribution*